# nvd3.js d3 tickformat is not working

Tags: d3.js, nvd3.js

I am using nvd3.js multiBarHorizontalChart http://nvd3.org/ghpages/multiBarHorizontal.html
I am trying to format the values into integer and get rid of the decimals.

```
 chart.yAxis
     .tickFormat(d3.format('d'));

  chart.xAxis
     .tickFormat(d3.format('d'));
```

http://jsfiddle.net/petran/4DAwU/

Answer (score 1):

You're putting the format specifier in the wrong place -- you want to format the values shown after the bars I presume. Do this using

```
chart.valueFormat(d3.format('d'));
```